# OpenGL point sprite uv coordinates not working correctly

Tags: c++, opengl

So I'm trying to render a grid in OpenGL using point sprites and render a cross texture on to the point. I've read on a few sites that you can access the uv coordinates of a point sprite in the fragment shader with gl_PointCoord, but for some reason it is always 0, unless I capture a frame with renderdoc to take a look at whats going on. I have the same issue on my Windows laptop (Nvidia GTX 960m) and on my Linux desktop (NVidia GTX 1070). So either this is an general issue of the NVidia drivers or I'm configuring something wrong.

For debugging purposes I increased the size of some grid points and set the color equal to gl_PointCoord. This is the captured framebuffer content after the grid has been rendered and the original window as comparison:
[image]

My rendering setup is pretty complex and scattered around different classes because it is wrapped inside a GUI library, but basically these are the calls that happen when rendering the grid:

```cpp
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, this->m_framebufferId);

    this->updateProjection(width, height);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
    glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_REPLACE);
    glClearColor(backgroundColor.m_red, backgroundColor.m_green, backgroundColor.m_blue, backgroundColor.m_alpha);
    glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

    <generate grid data>

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->gridVboId);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, 8 * this->pointCount, this->gridPoints);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->gridStyleTexture->getTextureId());

    glUseProgram(this->gridShaderProgram->getId());
    this->gridShaderProgram->setUniform4x4f("u_projectionMatrix", this->projectionMatrix);
    this->gridShaderProgram->setUniform1f("u_depth", this->gridMode == GRID_MODE_BACKGROUND ? -1000.0f : -1.0f);
    this->gridShaderProgram->setUniform1f("u_size", 1.0f);
    this->gridShaderProgram->setUniform1i("u_texture", 0);
    this->gridShaderProgram->setUniform2f("u_icon", 2.0f, 0.5f);
    this->gridShaderProgram->setUniform4f("u_color", this->gridColor);

    glEnable(GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE);
    glBindVertexArray(this->gridVaoId);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, this->pointCount);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glDisable(GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE);
    this->pointCount = 0;
```

This is the vertex shader:

```c
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec2 v_position;

uniform mat4 u_projectionMatrix;
uniform float u_depth;
uniform float u_size;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = u_projectionMatrix * vec4(v_position, u_depth, 1.0);
    gl_PointSize = u_size;
}
```

The Fragment shader:

```c
#version 330

layout (location = 0) out vec4 fragmentColor;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform vec2 u_icon;
uniform vec4 u_color;
uniform float u_size;

void main()
{
    if (u_size > 1.0)
        fragmentColor = vec4(gl_PointCoord, 0.0, 1.0);
    else
    {
        vec2 uvCoord = gl_PointCoord / vec2(1.0, u_icon.x) + vec2(0.0, u_icon.y);
        fragmentColor = texture(u_texture, uvCoord) * u_color;
    }
}
```

The big squares are rendered with the top branch because u_size is greater than 1, in the captured frame it is 15.0.

Is this a bug or am I missing some openGL calls to make it work correctly?

Comment: which GL context version and profile are you using?

Comment: I'm using GLFW to create a context with no specific profile selected. It creates a 4.6 profile on linux, should be the same on my Windows Laptop. I only use 3.3 methods though.

I use glad as loader, which I configured to be in core profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the additional comment:

> I'm using GLFW to create a context with no specific profile selected.

If you do not explicitly request a core profile, you will get either a legacy context (something before the invention of profiles in GL), or a *compatibility* profile. Since support for compatibility profiles is optional,you can not rely on getting the a context supporting GL 3.3 that. way.

> It creates a 4.6 profile on linux, should be the same on my Windows Laptop.

That's only luck. With the open source mesa driver on Linux, you will only get GL 3.0, and on MacOS, only 2.1.

> I use glad as loader, which I configured to be in core profile.

That doesn't matter. It won't change which version and profile your context supports. It will just limit the loaded functions to the subset GL 3.3 core provides.

However, my main point about asking for the the GL profile is that point sprite rendering differs significantly between core and compatibility profiles:

- In core profile OpenGL, point rendering will automatically be point sprite rendering
- In compatibility profiles, you have to explicitly enable this via `glEnable(GL_POINT_SPRITE)`, otherwise, `gl_PointCoord` will not be calculated.

> I've read on a few sites that you can access the uv coordinates of a point sprite in the fragment shader with `gl_PointCoord`, but for some reason it is always 0, unless I capture a frame with renderdoc to take a look at whats going on.

That doesn't surprise me then: renderdoc only works with core profile contexts, and most likely tweaks the context creation to a core profile in your case.

Since your code seems to target core profile anyway (and seems to work on that, too, judging by the experience you get with renderdoc), you should explicitly request a core profile. This will have the additional benefit of greatly increasing the number of implementations which can run your code.

The other solution would be to detect if you're running in core or compat profiles, and conditionally call `glEnable(GL_POINT_SPRITE)` (or, the quick&dirty variant: always call that and ignore the GL error which will be generated by this on core profile contexts). However, your glad loader's GL header probably will not even contain the `#define GL_POINT_SPRITE 0x8861` definition...

Comment: Specifcally requesting a core profile fixed the issue, thanks.